# Chromium Omnibox not showing search suggestions?

Tags: search, ubuntu-12.04, chromium, address-bar

Chromium omnibox is not showing suggestions, i have checked the settings, prediction is enabled.

When i changed the search engine to bing it was working fine with suggestions but when i revert back to google it stops showing the suggestions. My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Same problem, have you find something yet ?

Comment: @Melki No i couldn't find a solution. Moreover, i have got rid of an over hyped OS called ubuntu. I had to spend a lot of time in doing things which can be easily handled in Windows os.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of chromium, if not check after update.